# Ho to make Go to/Peek actions available in command pallete

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

In VS Code you can run (and configure) Go to/Peek actions
[from the command palette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKRr1.png).

However, it is not a case for Monaco editor. I can't find commands neither in palette, nor programmaticaly.

For example, the following command returns an empty array.

```js
editor.getActions().filter(x => x.id === 'editor.action.peekDefinition')
```

But in the same time, **Peek -> Peek Definition** is available in a right-click menu.

So, is there a way to make such commands available in `editor.getActions()` or in command palette?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a command, that is not specified as `action`, you can use the [trigger](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/typedoc/interfaces/editor.IEditor.html#trigger) API.

So, to run Go to/Peek actions you can use the following:

```js
editor.trigger('source', 'editor.action.revealDefinition'); // runs Go to definition for the symbol at current cursor position
editor.trigger('source', 'editor.action.peekDefinition'); // peeks symbol definition at current cursor position

editor.trigger('source', 'editor.action.goToReferences'); // runs Go to references... for the symbol at current cursor position
editor.trigger('source', 'editor.action.referenceSearch.trigger'); // peeks symbol references at current cursor position
```